# RNN for classification giving vastly different results (Keras)

Tags: classification, keras, rnn

I have a time series data (counts of the number of infectious individuals per day), and I am using a SimpleRNN from Keras to classify each of these epidemics into one of eight possible classes.

I used cross-validation to select the best number of hidden units, etc. My problem is that when I run the chosen model multiple times (that is when I train the model multiple times with the same architecture), I get very different results. I'm guessing this is a problem with many local minima, but I'm not sure - it could just be a problem with training. How can I diagnose this? I've done the following:

- Removed the patience term - I thought I might not be training long enough, and the wildly different classification errors were due to that.
- Changed my activation functions to ReLUs instead of using the default tanh units - maybe there's some saturation going on.
- Changed my `load_data` function to scale the input data (which are integers).

Can anyone think of anything else that I could do to try to figure out why the same code is giving me different classification errors?

EDIT: More information - I'm using an RNN for an 8-class classification task. There are 200 observations per class in the test set. I obtain confusion matrices for each of the 10 runs shown in the code below. Here are two of the confusion matrices:

```
189,0,0,0,0,11,0,0
0,197,0,0,0,3,0,0
0,0,199,0,0,1,0,0
1,0,0,195,0,0,0,4
0,0,0,0,200,0,0,0
26,0,0,0,0,174,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,200,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,5,195
```

That one's pretty good. It has an average classification error of 0.032.

(EDIT 2) Here is a plot of the training and validation accuracy for the well-performing run:

[image: trainval0]

This one, however, is much worse (average classification error of 0.389):

```
192,0,0,0,0,8,0,0
0,181,0,0,0,19,0,0
44,3,106,39,3,5,0,0
0,0,3,168,29,0,0,0
0,7,0,0,193,0,0,0
62,2,0,0,0,136,0,0
32,33,49,35,31,20,0,0
27,20,48,46,37,20,0,2
```

(EDIT 2) Here is a plot of the training and validation accuracy for the badly performing run (looks awful):

[image: trainval1]

(EDIT 2) New thought: could this be because of bad initial conditions after all? Why else would some runs be good and some be so bad?

Here is the code (EDITED to show the last two changes in the bullet points):

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    import numpy as np
    import pandas, math, sys, keras
    from keras import optimizers
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, SimpleRNN
    from keras.regularizers import l2
    from keras.utils import np_utils
    from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

  def load_data(train_file, test_file):
        trainset = np.loadtxt(train_file, delimiter=",")

        # split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
        X = trainset[:, 0:(trainset.shape[1]-2)] 
        Y = (trainset[:,trainset.shape[1]-1]).astype(int) 

        scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
        X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)

        y_binary = to_categorical(Y)

        testset = np.loadtxt(test_file, delimiter=",")
        X_test = testset[:,0:(testset.shape[1]-2)]
        X_test_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_test)

        Y_test = (testset[:,testset.shape[1]-1]).astype(int)

        X_train = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1))
        X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))

        ytest_binary = to_categorical(Y_test)

        return (X_train, y_binary, X_test, ytest_binary)

    def get_confusion_matrix_one_hot(model_results, truth):
        '''model_results and truth should be for one-hot format, i.e, have >= 2 columns,
        where truth is 0/1, and max along each row of model_results is model result
        '''
        assert model_results.shape == truth.shape
        num_outputs = truth.shape[1]
        confusion_matrix = np.zeros((num_outputs, num_outputs), dtype=np.int32)
        predictions = np.argmax(model_results,axis=1)
        assert len(predictions)==truth.shape[0]

        for actual_class in range(num_outputs):
            idx_examples_this_class = truth[:,actual_class]==1
            prediction_for_this_class = predictions[idx_examples_this_class]
            for predicted_class in range(num_outputs):
                count = np.sum(prediction_for_this_class==predicted_class)
                confusion_matrix[actual_class, predicted_class] = count
        assert np.sum(confusion_matrix)==len(truth)
        assert np.sum(confusion_matrix)==np.sum(truth)
        return confusion_matrix

    def rnn_repeat(X, Y, Xtest, Ytest, params_to_use, save_file="rnn_twolayer_acc_loss", num_reps=10):

        def rnn_model(hid_dim=10, ker_reg=0.01, rec_reg=0.01, optimizer="sgd"):
                model = Sequential()
                model.add(SimpleRNN(units=hid_dim, activation='relu', input_shape = (X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), kernel_regularizer=l2(ker_reg), recurrent_regularizer = l2(rec_reg), return_sequences = False))
                model.add(Dense(Y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
                model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
                print 'fitting a model'
                return model

        optim = params_to_use['optimizer']
        ker_reg_best = params_to_use['ker_reg']
        hid_val = params_to_use['hid_dim']
        rec_reg_best = params_to_use['rec_reg']

        #Need this for all classification errors
        class_error = []

        #X has 6400 examples, 800 of each class (8 classes). Take 20% of each class and make this the validation set.
        to_take = np.random.choice(800, int(800*0.2), replace=False)
        class_split = np.array_split(X, 8) #16 equal slices of 800 elements each
        val_list = [x[to_take] for x in class_split]
        big_list = [item for sublist in val_list for item in sublist]
        val_X = np.asarray(big_list)
        label_set = np.arange(0, 8) #0 to 15
        val_Y = np.repeat(label_set, int(800*0.2))
        val_Y = to_categorical(val_Y)

        setdiffval = set(range(800)) - set(to_take)
        setdiffval = list(setdiffval)

        X_train_vals = [x[setdiffval] for x in class_split]
        X_train = [item for sublist in X_train_vals for item in sublist]
        X_train = np.asarray(X_train)
        Y_train = np.repeat(label_set, int(800*0.8))
        Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train)

        for j in range(num_reps):
            model = rnn_model(hid_dim=hid_val, ker_reg=ker_reg_best, rec_reg=rec_reg_best, optimizer=optim)
            hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(val_X, val_Y), epochs=200)
            h1 = hist.history
            acc_ = np.asarray(h1['acc'])
            loss_ = np.asarray(h1['loss'])
            val_loss_ = np.asarray(h1['val_loss'])
            val_acc_ = np.asarray(h1['val_acc'])

            #Save the accuracy and loss
            acc_and_loss = np.column_stack((acc_, loss_, val_acc_, val_loss_))
            save_file_rnn = save_file + '_' + str(j) + '.txt'
            with open(save_file_rnn, 'w') as f:
                    np.savetxt(save_file_rnn, acc_and_loss, delimiter=" ")
            print 'saved file', save_file_rnn

            #Run the final, trained model on the test set and return a confusion matrix
            test_scores = model.evaluate(Xtest, Ytest) #evaluate returns the metric 'accuracy' on the test set
            print 'eval_scores', test_scores[1]*100
            predict = model.predict(Xtest) #I think predict returns the class probabilities
            con_mat = get_confusion_matrix_one_hot(predict, Ytest)
            print con_mat

            #Save the confusion matrix
            save_con_mat = 'confusionmatrix_rnn' + '_' + str(j) + '.txt'
            np.savetxt(save_con_mat, con_mat, fmt='%i', delimiter=",")

            #Get the classification error per class, and the average classification error
            class_error_j = []
            for i in range(0, con_mat.shape[1]): #for the number of classes
                class_i_correct = float(con_mat[i][i])/float(sum(con_mat[i]))
                class_error_j.append(1. - class_i_correct)

            class_error_j.append(sum(class_error_j)/con_mat.shape[1]) #the average classification error
            class_error.append(class_error_j) #each class's classification error, and the average classification error for this run

        np.savetxt('class_error.txt', class_error, fmt = '%1.3f', delimiter=' ')

        return 0

    if __name__=='__main__':

        X, Y, Xtest, Ytest = load_data('train.csv', 'test.csv')
        best_params = {'rec_reg': 0.01, 'optimizer': 'adam', 'ker_reg': 0.1, 'hid_dim': 15} 
        rnn_repeat(X, Y, Xtest, Ytest, best_params)
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there anything wrong with how I phrased the question?

Comment: Can you expand on the "very different results" bit? Are you sure your model is converging in the 200 epochs you are training it over? Can you show us the learning curves for the test- and train sets?

Comment: Thanks @Emre, I'm having trouble getting those right now but as soon as I do, I'll post them.

Comment: [Here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/display-deep-learning-model-training-history-in-keras/)'s a tutorial. Welcome to the site and good luck.

Comment: @Emre Thank you. I have added curves for the training and validation accuracy.

Comment: It could be bad initialization or underfitting; small networks run into local optima more often. I would use the steady state distributions of the parameters (esp. the kernels) on good runs for initialization. You can [visualize distributions with tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/histogram).

Comment: Hmm. Do you mean that I should initialize the next run using the values of the final weights from a successful run? Doesn't that introduce bias? Also, what do you mean by 'especially the kernels'?

Comment: No, I mean you should draw from a similar _distribution_, not use the same values. The same kernel you regularized in the second line of `rnn_model()`

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure we were on the same page terminology-wise. Keras uses 'kernel' to mean the weights from the input to the hidden layer, so 'kernel_regularizer' is a regularization term on that weights matrix, and 'recurrent_regularizer' is a regularization term on the weights between hidden layers. Still not sure what you mean by the steady state distribution in this case. It's not MCMC, I'm not learning a posterior distribution on the parameters - am I?

Comment: Yes, I meant the weights of the activation function. By steady state I meant the regime in which the loss has converged and the distribution of the weights should not be changing much. Just look at the first order statistics. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Okay, if I understand correctly, you're recommending that I build an empirical distribution of the learned weights from the point at which the loss converges, and initialize the parameters for the next run from that empirical distribution. No idea how to do that. I'll ask a separate question. Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to do it exactly; a uniform or truncated normal approximation  should suffice. You can visualize these distributions using [tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/histogram).

Comment: This is going to sound really silly - what do you mean by first order statistics? That term means 'minimum' to me.

Comment: I should have said the first and second _moments_. You are right; I made a mistake.

Comment: Phew - thanks! I agree, I would definitely want the same mean and variance. Now to figure out how to do it.